# Moment parse strange behavior with hours

Tags: momentjs

I would like to understand why moment.js is changing minutes to "04" every time I parse, what am I doing wrong?

```js
var sDate = '2017-04-24';
var sHour = '16:54:10';
alert(moment(sDate + ' ' + sHour).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS'));
alert(moment.utc(sDate + 'T' + sHour).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS'));
alert(moment(sDate + ' 00:00:00').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js">
```

Accordinly to the official docs it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment tokens are case sensitive, please note that uppercase `M` stands for months while you have to use lowecase `m` for showing minutes.

See [formatting docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Note that you probably have to change `SS` (fractional seconds) to `ss` (seconds) too.

Your code will be like the following:

```js
var sDate = '2017-04-24';
var sHour = '16:54:10';
alert(moment(sDate + ' ' + sHour).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Man now i'm feeling really embarrassed, spend a couple of hours in this, that I didn't realize this silly mistake. Thank you.